# how do I return values from a `async Task` function?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, async-await

I need to return the value `submitOut` from  `async Task testWCF2` function below?Can anyone provide guidance on how to do it?

```
    public static async Task testWCF2(string xmlConfig)
    {
        string submitOut;

        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var url = "http://server:8100/api/SoftwareProductBuild";
            var content = new StringContent(xmlConfig, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                submitOut = responseBody;
            }
            else
            {
                submitOut = string.Format("Bad Response {0} \n", response.StatusCode.ToString());
                submitOut = submitOut + response;
            }
        }
    }

    public string QlasrSubmit(List<XMLSiInfo> xmlConfigs)
    {
        string submitOut = "QLASR: ";

        foreach (XMLSiInfo xmlConfig in xmlConfigs)
        {
            submitOut = submitOut + "\n" + testWCF2(xmlConfig.xml).ToString();
        }

        return submitOut;
    }

    public string QlasrPostcommit(string si, string sp, string variant = null)
    {
        .............
        string submitStatus            = QlasrSubmit(siInfo);
        ....
        return submitStatus;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your return type to `Task<string>`, as such:

```
public static async Task<string> testWCF2(string xmlConfig)
```

Then you can just `return submitOut;`

Once you are returning a value, then you consume it using `await`:

```
public async Task<string> QlasrSubmit(List<XMLSiInfo> xmlConfigs)
{
  string submitOut = "QLASR: ";

  foreach (XMLSiInfo xmlConfig in xmlConfigs)
  {
    submitOut = submitOut + "\n" + await testWCF2(xmlConfig.xml);
  }

  return submitOut;
}
```

I recommend reading up on the [basics of `async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: -  Updated my question a bit ,it throws an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'` at line `string submitStatus            = QlasrSubmit(siInfo);`

Comment: is there a solution without converting `QlasrPostcommit` return type to `Task<string>`

Comment: @user3508811: `QlasrSubmit` is also asynchronous now, so you'll need to consume it with `await`.

Comment: @user3508811: If you're going to use `async`, you should [use `async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); is there some reason you don't want to?

Comment: Now I have the return type at multiple places,is there a way to post `await client.PostAsync` with async and await,I get the error `"QLASR: \nSystem.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]` with these Threading tasks,so trying to avoid

Answer (score 3):

```
public static async Task<string> testWCF2(string xmlConfig)
{
    string submitOut;

    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        var url = "http://server:8100/api/SoftwareProductBuild";
        var content = new StringContent(xmlConfig, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            submitOut = responseBody;
        }
        else
        {
            submitOut = string.Format("Bad Response {0} \n", response.StatusCode.ToString());
            submitOut = submitOut + response;
        }
    }

    return submitOut;
}
```