# How to post a webapi call using async and await

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am trying write a webapi which tries to post a webapi call using async and await,my current issue is as soon as I call `await client.PostAsync(url, content);` it hangs.

1.How to debug why it is hanging?

2.Is there a way to do it without async and await?I want to do it sequentially

```
    public static async Task<string> testWCF2(string xmlConfig)
    {
        string submitOut;

        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var url = "http://server:8100/api/SoftwareProductBuild";
            var content = new StringContent(xmlConfig, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                submitOut = responseBody;
            }
            else
            {
                submitOut = string.Format("Bad Response {0} \n", response.StatusCode.ToString());
                submitOut = submitOut + response;
            }
        }

        return submitOut;
    }

    public async Task<string> QlasrSubmit(List<XMLSiInfo> xmlConfigs)
    {
        string submitOut = "QLASR: ";

        foreach (XMLSiInfo xmlConfig in xmlConfigs)
        {
           submitOut = submitOut + "\n" + await testWCF2(xmlConfig.xml);
        }

        return submitOut;
    }


    public async Task<string> QlasrPostcommit(string si, string sp, string variant = null)
    {
        .....
        string submitStatus     = await QlasrSubmit(siInfo);
        .....
        return submitStatus;
    }
```

Service:

```
    public async Task<string> QlasrPostcommit(string si, string sp, string variant = null)
    {
        return await DPR.QlasrPostcommit(si, sp, variant);
    }
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/DevPool/QlasrPostcommit")]
[HttpPost]
public ResponseObject QlasrPostcommit(string si, string sp, string variant = null)
{
    ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject();
    try
    {
        response.status = 200;
        response.data = DPS.QlasrPostcommit(si, sp, variant);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response.status = 200;
        response.data = null;
        response.message = e.Message;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to call it using another tool such  as Postman  is the best way to debug I  think

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel - Is there a simple way to post a webapi call in C# ,this is so complex just for posting a webapi,so much simpler in python..

Comment: in  c# is simple to but you should be sure that you can call your api without an issue

Comment: am not finding this simple with all the async and await,running into threading issues,all I want is post a webapi call and return the response..for that I was forced to use async and await which forces every API call has the same return type as you can see from my code

Comment: \\you should be sure that you can call your api without an issue --> don't now what you mean here...what issues you are referring to?

Comment: One thing you should **not** be doing is creating a new `HttpClient` for every request.  Use a static class member `HttpClient`

Comment: @maccettura - Can you expand on what exactly you mean?

Comment: @JeffShort I don't necessarily think its the cause of your issue, but its good practice to not new up a client.  [This](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) blog article covers it.

Comment: @JeffShort check to make sure you are not mixing async/await and blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait` higher up the call stack which can cause dead locks. Next, based on service method shown you also need to make the controller action async as well

Comment: @Nkosi good catch on the controller action.  @JeffShort, make sure you mark that controller action as: `public async Task<ResponseObject> QlasrPostcommit(string si, string sp, string variant = null)` and then **await** your call: `response.data = await DPS.QlasrPostcommit(si, sp, variant);`

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), as I mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043960/how-do-i-return-values-from-a-async-task-function/45044110#45044110):

```
[Route("api/DevPool/QlasrPostcommit")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ResponseObject> QlasrPostcommit(string si, string sp, string variant = null)
{
  ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject();
  try
  {
    response.status = 200;
    response.data = await DPS.QlasrPostcommit(si, sp, variant);
    return response;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    response.status = 200;
    response.data = null;
    response.message = e.Message;
    return response;
  }
}
```

In this particular case, you're running into a [deadlock because you're blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and it works perfectly, without deallock and with waiting result!!

You have fix the Service:

```
public string QlasrPostcommit(string si, string sp, string variant = null)
    {
 Task<string > task = Task.Run<string >(async () => await 
      DPR.QlasrPostcommit(si, sp, variant));
      task.Result;    
    }
```

***Generic answer:***

```
public TypeToReturn MyAsyncMethod(myParams...)
        {
     Task<TypeToReturn> task = Task.Run<TypeToReturn>(async () => await 
          MyAsyncMethod(myParams...));
          task.Result;    
        }
```